# Convert string to local int to calculate

Tags: c#, converters

I'm trying to calculate some properties but I'm not sure how how do it. 
the proporties are of type `string` and I know that `string` values can't calculate. So I though about making them int.

```
    public class ItemProperties
            {
                public string Item { get; set; }
                public string Description { get; set; }
                public string Quantity { get; set; }
                public string UnitPrice { get; set; }
                public string Tax { get; set; }

                public int TotalPay { get { return Quantity * UnitPrice; } set; }
                 //Now I get error on the line above because string can't calculate

            }
```

> Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and
>   'string'

So basically I need to convert the `string` `Quantity` and `UnitPrice` to local `int` variables and then use them to calculate. Can anyone help me out?

**UPDATE:**

Here is the code that assigns the properties to `string[]`

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialog.FileName);
for (var i = 9; i + 2 < lines.Length; i += 6)
            {
                Items.Add(new ItemProperties { 
                    Item = lines[i],
                    Description = lines[i + 1],
                    Quantity = lines[i + 2],
                    UnitPrice = lines[i + 3],
                    Tax = lines[i + 4]
                });
            }
            itemlst.ItemsSource = Items;
```

Comment: Why can't you make Quantity and UnitPrice ints?
public int Quantity { get; set; }
public int UnitPrice { get; set; }

Comment: Because I'm assigning them to `array of strings` varibales

Comment: Why don't you convert them to strings before adding them to the array?

Comment: @RufusL I don't know how to do it. Can you help me out?

Comment: Why don't you modify the properties to be **descriptive** datatypes (`string, string, int, double, double` in that order in your case), and then use them in that manner?

Comment: @EBrown you mean when assigning them? like this? `string Item = lines[i];`

Comment: No, I mean `public int Quantity`, and then `Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(lines[i + 2]),`

Comment: You're welcome, you can also do the same thing with `public double UnitPrice` and then `UnitPrice = Convert.ToDouble(lines[i + 3]),`.

Answer (score 3):

The quick way (no error checking) would be:

```
    public int TotalPay { get { return Convert.ToInt32(Quantity) * Convert.ToInt32(UnitPrice); } }
```

A bit more robust version:

```
    public int TotalPay
    {
        get
        {
            int qty;
            int price;

            if (int.TryParse(Quantity, out qty) && int.TryParse(UnitPrice, out price))
            {
                return qty * price;
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }
```

This solves your current problem but if the properties hold int data, they should be defined as int.

The code that assigns them to arrays of strings should convert the int properties to strings, not the other way around.

**EDIT**
This will convert the string property read from the file into an int. Be aware that this will cause errors if the values in the file are not ints. You should have some error handling to cater for that.

```
public class ItemProperties
{
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public string Tax { get; set; }

    public int TotalPay
    {
        get
        {
            return Quantity * UnitPrice;
        }
    }
}

    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialog.FileName);

    for (var i = 9; i + 2 < lines.Length; i += 6)
        {
            Items.Add(new ItemProperties
            {
                Item = lines[i],
                Description = lines[i + 1],
                Quantity =  Convert.ToInt32(lines[i + 2]),
                UnitPrice = Convert.ToInt32(lines[i + 3]),
                Tax = lines[i + 4]
            });
        }
        itemlst.ItemsSource = Items;
```

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question there I show the assignment to the string. Can you help convert the int properties to strings before the assignments are done

Comment: Why is `Tax` still a `string`, and `UnitPrice` an `int`? You would think they would be `double UnitPrice` (or `float UnitPrice`) and `double Tax` (or `float Tax`).

Comment: Yes, one could assume so. However those are business rules specific to OP's domain and he has to change them. I'm merely suggesting the changes he needs to make to answer OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the mentioned properties integer if they represent integer data.
You can use the static `Convert` class to parse a string as an integer, e.g.:

```
public class ItemProperties
{
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public int Tax { get; set; }

    public int TotalPay { get { return Quantity * UnitPrice; } set; }

}
```

Using:

```
ItemProperties prop;
try
{
    prop.Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(stringVar);
}
catch(FormatException)
{
    // error handling
}
```

Comment: The `System.Convert` class is static: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Oh, I meant in your code. I though you were suppose to include the static in the code example you gave. My bad